# casting an int to a long pointer

Tags: c++, c, casting

```
int test = 1;
cout << (long *) &test <<endl; //=0x7fff7370cefc
cout << (long) test <<endl; //= 1
```

Can someone explain what is happening in the first case?
I get that long > int, thus the jibberish number, but what exactly is happening?

Comment: You're not "casting an int to a long pointer", you're casting an int *pointer* to a long pointer.

Comment: _'casting an int to a long pointer'_ usually calls for trouble :-/ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case:

```
cout << (long *) &test <<endl; //=0x7fff7370cefc
```

you in fact are **giving the value, of the address of `test` variable, to be converted into a long pointer value** and then printed. Which is exactly what you should get.

Comment: so the address value is printed on the screen?

Comment: yes of course, it is the address value, and that is what you are doing here:)

Comment: @mightyuhu the `&` operator indicates to take the address.